# How to get table names and their data types from session/engine/meta in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a Model:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    nickname = Column(String(50))
```

Now in code, I want all the data types of the User class, what is the best possible way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `__table__` attribute of your model and interact with the column elements directly:

```py
for for x in User.__table__.c:
    print(x, x.type)
>> users.id INTEGER
>> users.name VARCHAR(50)
>> users.fullname VARCHAR(50)
>> users.nickname VARCHAR(50)
```